# Laravel show errors in view

Tags: php, error-handling, laravel, laravel-4

if my validation fails I do this:

```
return Redirect::back()->with('validation', $validation->errors->all());
```

also I am using:

```
$restful = true;
```

so when I am on `get_edit()` - I'am getting an error that there are no $validation variable when generating my view, when in `post_edit()` - its all okay because its returns a redirect with errors...

this is my view:

```
<? foreach($validation as $e): ?>

<div><?= $e; ?></div>

<? endforeach; ?>
```

undefined variable $validation, right now I'am trying to put it on the Router::before

```
Route::filter('before', function()
{
    View::share('validation', array());
});
```

so the variable exists but is empty, but now arises a new problem, everytime after this filter executes it overrides those `$validation` that generates my `post_edit()`, also i've seen a variable `$errors` in my view but is ever empty, i don't how to use it, can you help me?

so shortly my problem is:

```
public function get_edit($id)
{
   //generate my view with all nessesary data, but i can't generate here an error variable
   // or its better to put it in one place to globally share it in the views, otherwise i am     //getting an error
}

public function post_edit($id)
{

  //validating $_POST data, if there is an error redirect it back to the get_edit() WITH a        //variable containing errors

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you read the docs? http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#error-messages-and-views

You can use `return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validation);`
In your views, you can always use redirect('register')->withErrors($validator)`$errors`, without binding them to the view.